# Header file not found when compiling Vowpal Wabbit on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, boost, osx-mavericks, vowpalwabbit

I have downloaded Vowpal Wabbit ( Version 7.4 ) on to my Mac ( OS X Mavericks ) with the following version of g++ :

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-   dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

I modified the Makefile that comes with the installation so that it will pick up Boost ( Version 1.55 ) headers and libraries from the correct folders on my Mac ( I checked by writing and compiling a simple program and everything works ). However, when I run **make** it cannot find a header file, for example:

```
In file included from library_example.cc:2:
./../vowpalwabbit/parser.h:15:10: fatal error: 'boost/program_options.hpp' file
  not found
```

Grateful for any help in tracking down the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vowpal wabbit has a dependency on the C++ library+headers `boost/program_options`.

This dependency must be installed before vowpal wabbit can be built from source.

Since other people may have a similar issue, I will try to answer the more general question:

***How to build vowpal wabbit from scratch/source, on Mac OS-X?***

The following set of instructions assumes you have no development environment at all.  If you do, you may skip any steps you deem unnecessary.

Important: credit where credit is due. These instructions are almost 100% written by ***Aaron Shumacher***: I sourced them from [his page](https://planspace.org/2013/02/02/install-vowpal-wabbit-on-mac-os-x/) following a web-search, with relatively minor modifications, additions, and clarifications.

**Stage 0, basic prerequisites needed for developing on Mac OS-X:**

- Install the [`Xcode`](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) command line tools. This will give you an Apple’s development environment (compiler, make, etc.).
- Install the [`Homebrew`](https://brew.sh) package manager.

Once you have `Homebrew` installed, everything else that's missing, is easy to install.

**Install needed tools to build from source:**

```
brew install libtool
brew install automake
brew install boost
brew install git
```

Now, you're ready to download the vowpal wabbit source tree (latest):

**Download:**

```
git clone https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit.git
cd vowpal_wabbit
```

You’re now ready to go through the standard build (aka `make`) process.

**Build:**

[Edit: 2014-07-20]: `./autogen.sh` may not work well in some environments. I recommend trying to build using a simple `make` first.  The included `Makefile` is already pretty robust and should work just fine in most environments. The problem with running `autogen/automake` is that it may overwrite the (pretty good) original `Makefile` with a bad one.

```
# ./autogen.sh  # commented out, use only if 'make' alone doesn't work
make
make test
```

Note: it is important to verify (using `make test`) that your binary works as expected.  If you see any failure, please report it on the mailing list, and proceed with the installation only if the failure is immaterial to you (e.g. only some rarely used options/tests you don't care about fail).  See the `test/RunTests` script for full details on the tests.

**Install:**

```
make install
```

At this point, you should have vowpal wabbit at `/usr/local/bin/vw`

Comment: The site's [rules for giving credit to sources](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) require links.  Have you lost the URL of Aaron's page which you provided a foundation for your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the instructions which I followed and everything is working.

Comment: Hi - Thanks! I haven't updated that post in a while either; it probably needed some tweaking to get it to work! :)

Comment: One slight addendum - I had to alter the AC_PATH variable in autogen.sh from /opt/local/share to /usr/local/share, in order to get autogen to find the brew installed automake files. It also looks like the glibtoolize edit step is no longer required, as the autogen.sh on the git master of vowpal wabbit now checks the architecture of the system and chooses the right command.

Comment: Thank you, @mistertim, I'll delete the glibtoolize noise as it is no longer needed.  Would it be possible for you to send a github pull request to John Langford (master) with the AC_PATH fix?  This would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @arielf - sure! will do that today.

Comment: You can also `brew install vowpal-wabbit`, which automatically takes care of all of the above steps.